# Generate key hash in xamarin android for facebook sdk

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I want to give login using facebook facility in my xamarin android app.

Can anyone tell me , how to generate key hash for xamarin android
 I have saw this on developers.facebook.com to generate key hash

**keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64**

can anyone tell me, what is meaning of each and every word in this command?
 What values should be given to these variables?such as what is alias? Where can I find this and other too.
 As I am new to facebook development , I don't know all these terms. It will be nice if someone gives me any example of this.
 Please help me.
 I am completely stuck here.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.local/share/Xamarin/Mono\ for\ Android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

The default keystore password is **android**.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get a list of parameters of keytool and openssl by entring 'keytool ?' or 'keytool -help' and figure out everything:

```
Commands:
 -certreq            Generates a certificate request
 -changealias        Changes an entry's alias
 -delete             Deletes an entry
 -exportcert         Exports certificate
 -genkeypair         Generates a key pair
 -genseckey          Generates a secret key
 -gencert            Generates certificate from a certificate request
 -importcert         Imports a certificate or a certificate chain
 -importpass         Imports a password
 -importkeystore     Imports one or all entries from another keystore
 -keypasswd          Changes the key password of an entry
 -list               Lists entries in a keystore
 -printcert          Prints the content of a certificate
 -printcertreq       Prints the content of a certificate request
 -printcrl           Prints the content of a CRL file
 -storepasswd        Changes the store password of a keystore
```

as for the example of usage: I just created one:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin>keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\\Users\\.android\\debug.keystore" | "C:\\OpenSSL\\bin\\openssl" sha1 -binary |"C:\\OpenSSL\bin\\openssl" base64
```

you need to be in java bin path in your CMD:

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin>

and enter this command:

> keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\.android\debug.keystore" | "C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary |"C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" base64

Make sure you have openssl installed in your desired path but modify the path in your command respectively.

And by the way. openssl no longer produce windows installer binaries so you need to get it from 3rd parties

[Here For Example](http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Windows:
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64

Mac OSX:
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64

Answer (score 0):

You may get the hash key using two steps. One is through command prompt. Another one is through coding. Hash key through command prompt working on the first time only. I don't know the reason. I have also got the same problem. So i tried it through programmatically.

```
        try
        {

            PackageInfo info = PackageManager.GetPackageInfo(
                        "com.example.packagename",
                        PackageInfoFlags.Signatures);
            foreach (var signature in info.Signatures)
            {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.GetInstance("SHA");
                md.Update(signature.ToByteArray());
                Log.Debug("KeyHash:", Base64.EncodeToString(md.Digest(), Base64.Default));
                var s = Base64.EncodeToString(md.Digest(), Base64.Default);
            }
        }
        catch (NameNotFoundException e)
        {

        }
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
        {

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

On my windows laptop I have to do this in two steps to get the correct hash (maybe due to variations in versions of keytool and openssl):

1. Export the certificate to file
2. Compute the hash on the file

On a command line (or in a batch file) run:

```
    "c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin\keytool.exe" -exportcert -keystore "%LocalAppData%\Xamarin\Mono for Android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android -file _temp.cert
    openssl sha1 -binary _temp.cert | openssl base64
    del _temp.cert
```